# Como añadir codigo HTML a query en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, mail

Estoy usando el Database Mail de SQL Server Management Studio 2014, para enviar correos después de que se ejecute un stored procedure, el problema es que no quiero que se envié un texto plano, si no una plantilla que ya tengo definida en **HTML** pero lo único que le llega al usuario en el cuerpo del correo, es el mismo código HTML.

El siguiente es parte del codigo que tengo en mi store procedure con el cual construyo el cuerpo del correo y le asigno los parametros respectivos

```
    SET @MAIL_BODY = 
    '<html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body width="100%" height="100%" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" bgcolor="#e0e0e0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <center style="width: 100%;">
                    <div style="max-width: 600px;">                        
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                        </table>               
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding-top: 40px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right:10px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">CONTENTID</tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="border-radius: 3px; text-align: center; padding: 40px 160px 0 160px;">
                                    <a style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; padding: 0 10px;color: #ffffff; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">
                                        FOLIO: '+@FOLIO+ 
                                    '</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="padding: 40px;padding-right:10px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;">
                                                <strong>Título de ticket:</strong> '+@TITLE +'
                                                <br>
                                                <strong>Descripción de Ticket:</strong> '+@CONTENT +'
                                                <br>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="padding: 40px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #888888;">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>'

    SET @SUBJECT = 
    'Ticket de servicio: ' +@FOLIO

    SET @MAIL_ENVIO = @CUSTOMER_EMAIL

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'Prueba',
    @recipients = @MAIL_ENVIO,
    @body = @MAIL_BODY,
    @subject = @SUBJECT
    END
```

Al final ejecuto el store procedure `sp_send_dbmail` que ya tengo creado y el perfil `Prueba` con la cuenta asociada a el.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola amigo creo que el problema es que no estas poniendo que sera un HTML.

Algo asi.

```
EXEC sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name='DatabaseEmailProfile',
  @copy_recipients ='aasc@stackexchange.com',
  @recipients='aa.sc@outlook.com',
  @subject='Query Result',
  @body=@Body ,
  @body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

Fuente

> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83776/need-to-send-a-formatted-html-email-via-database-mail-in-sql-server-2008-r2